# Angular update timeslot based on date changes

Tags: angular

i have 24 timeslot of hour each, then based on selected date, data from database updates the hours to booked status with user details. When i change the date it don`t reset the previous one, but add new ones on top.

I have a sample project on stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-update-timeslot-based-on-date-changes)

```
defaultSlots: Array<any> = [
  { hour: 1, booked: false, name: '' },
  { hour: 2, booked: false, name: '' }
]

date = { hour: 1, booked: true, name: "Jassi" }

// This is used in HTML
timeSlots = [...this.defaultSlots];

constructor() { }

update() {
  this.timeSlots[0].booked = this.date.booked;
  this.timeSlots[0].name = this.date.name;
}

reset() {
  this.timeSlots = [...this.defaultSlots];
}
```

Reset don`t reset to defaultSlots.

Comment: After lot of search, finally i have find the real question to ask, "Deep clone array of objects in ES6 " . But still no good answer.

Comment: Finally, i solved it  with lodash `s   _.cloneDeep()